# Target .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and .NET Framework 4 (full) in the same solution

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a Solution which contains an ASP.NET Web Application project.  Web Application project types can only target the *full* .NET Framework 4, and Visual Studio won't let you select the *Client Profile*.

However, my Class Library projects in that same solution allow me to target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

**So, should I mix targeting the *Client Profile* and the *full* framework in the same solution?  Or just target the *full* framework for every project type in a Solution containing a Web Application project?  Or does it not matter either way?**

Comment: target full since it gonna run on server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to reuse the Class Library in a WPF or WinForms app, then Client Profile is a good choice, since you are likely going to be able to set your WPF or WinForms app to use Client Profile as well. Even if your WPF or WinForms app ends up requiring the full framework, Client Profile is a subset of the full framework so it will still work just fine.

If your reuse plans on the Class Library are WebApp only or your only using a Class Library to help segment code, then the target framework is really not important.

Answer (score 1):

> Applications that target the .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile typically
>   improve the deployment experience by
>   having smaller download sizes and
>   quicker install times. An application
>   that targets the .NET Framework 4
>   Client Profile has a smaller
>   redistribution package that installs
>   the minimum set of client assemblies
>   on the user's computer, without
>   requiring the full version of the .NET
>   Framework 4 to be present.

If your library is general purpose and the target equipment will be installed with Client Profile Framework then *prefer client profile for your library*, by doing this you will have smaller installers. Web Components are not included when installed Client Profile Framework.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx